# Vue JS - Find the router history -1

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Is it possible with Vue2 to see where...

```
this.$router.go(-1)
```

Will take you?

We have a use case to redirect the user to last page they were on after they signed in, unless that is the forgot your password page. In that case we would want to send them back to the home page.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

### Vue 2 with Vue Router 3

You could use `beforeRouteEnter` navigation guard to track the previous route (stored in `from`):

```js
export default {
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      vm._backRoute = from.path
    })
  },
  methods: {
    goBack() {
      if (this._backRoute === '/reset-password') {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' })
      } else {
        this.$router.go(-1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-track-previous-route?file=src/views/Contact.vue)

### Vue 3 with Vue Router 4

You could read [`window.history.state.back`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/state) to see what the *back*-state would be beforehand:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    goBack() {
      if (window.history.state.back === '/reset-password') {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' })
      } else {
        this.$router.go(-1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-router-get-history-state?file=src/views/Contact.vue)

Comment: I appreciate this one but should have mentioned we are using Vue2 looks like this is happening in createWebHistory in the router. Using the window.history.state.back I am just getting undefined.

Comment: @Travis With Vue 2 and Vue Router 3, use `beforeRouteEnter` to track the previous route. See updated answer.